# Finding Lagrange Error Bound

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

So I was given the following prompt:

"Let $f$ be a function that has derivatives of all orders for all real numbers, and let $P_3(x)$ be the third-degree Taylor polynomial for $f$ about $x=0$. The Taylor series for $f$ about $x=0$ converges at $x=1$, and $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq\frac{n}{n+1}$, for $1\leq n\leq4$ and all values of $x$. What is the smallest value of $k$ for which the Lagrange error bound guarantees that $|f(1)-P_3(1)|\leq k$?"

I guess I'm confused about what the application of the formula used to find the Lagrange bound would look like in a situation like this. I understand that given an equation I would have to apply it to the formula of $|S-S_k|\leq b_{k+1}$ where the error is bounded by $b_{k+1}$, but I'm confused over how I'd apply that knowledge in this context. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello.  What does 'all values of $f_1$ mean?

Comment: Should be fixed, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Then all you need is $\displaystyle |f(1) - P_3(1)| = \left\lvert \frac{1^4}{4!}f^{(4)}(\xi)\right\rvert $ for $\xi \in (0,1)$ and the right side is bounded by $\frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{4!}$.  That gives the best estimate for $k$ given the available information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lagrange error bound of a Taylor polynomial gives the worst-case scenario error of the Taylor approximation on some interval. It levarages the fact that a Taylor-approximation of order n has an error of order n+1. More preciesely
$$(\forall x_0 \in I), (\forall n \in \mathbb{Z_+}), (\exists \xi \in I), \text{ s.t. } f(x) - T_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} (x-x_0)^{n+1}$$
This error term can be bounded by above as follows:
$$\bigg| \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} \bigg| \le \max_{t \in I} \bigg|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!} \bigg| = M_n$$
And this is the Lagrange error bound of the n-th order Taylor polynomial.